# Subtracting the results of two queries

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I have a DB with a query telling me how many keys total per specific room and another indicating how many per specific room are currently signed out. I'd like a create a third query indicating how many per room are now available.

Access File: http://jumpshare.com/b/k7pEg4

Query 1 (Keys per room)

```
SELECT r.room_name, count(r.room_id) AS Key_Count
FROM keys AS k 
INNER JOIN rooms AS r ON r.room_id = k.room_id
GROUP BY r.room_id, r.room_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Query 2 (KPR Signedout)

```
SELECT r.room_name, Count(r.room_id) AS Key_Count
FROM rooms AS r 
INNER JOIN (keys AS k 
INNER JOIN signin AS s ON k.key_id = s.key_id) ON r.room_id = k.room_id
WHERE (((s.[return_date]) Is Null))
GROUP BY r.room_name, r.room_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This is the result from query 1 and 2. If Room FY218 has 8 total keys and 2 keys currently signed out. Can I combine my queries to tell me this room has 6 keys remaining. If not how can I get this result.

[image]

These are my table and relationships:

[image]

Comment: What's the definition of `available`?

Comment: By the way your queries are wrong, i.e. the first should be: `SELECT r.room_name, count(k.key_id) AS Key_Count
FROM keys AS k INNER JOIN rooms AS r ON r.room_id = k.room_id
GROUP BY r.room_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC;`, and the second `SELECT r.room_name, Count(k.key_id) AS Key_Count
FROM rooms AS r INNER JOIN keys AS k ON r.room_id = k.room_id
INNER JOIN signin AS s ON k.key_id = s.key_id WHERE s.[return_date] Is Null
GROUP BY r.room_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC;`

Comment: By available I mean how many keys total for each room. I should reword the OP that might be confusing.

Comment: I can't understand your question, can you formulate it more formally?

Comment: Sorry I'll edit OP to make it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
SELECT r.room_name, Count(k.key_id) AS Key_Count
FROM rooms AS r
INNER JOIN keys AS k ON r.room_id = k.room_id 
WHERE k.key_id NOT IN (
    SELECT k2.key_id
    FROM keys AS k2
    INNER JOIN signin AS s ON k2.key_id = s.key_id
    WHERE s.[return_date] Is Null)
GROUP BY r.room_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Should the nested select k.key_id be k2.key_id
The query isn't returning any values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT
r.room_name,
Count(*) -
(
  SELECT Count(*)
  FROM keys AS k2
  INNER JOIN signin s2
  ON s2.key_id = k2.key_id
  WHERE r.room_id = k2.room_id
) AS AvailableKeys
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN keys AS k
ON r.room_id = k.room_id
GROUP BY r.room_name, r.room_id
```

Comment: The results from this don't add up. This is the result im getting http://jumpshare.com/v/mITRHc?b=77pEFd

It adds up to 24 keys remaining but there are only 9 signed out and 50 in the table total, therefore the remaining keys should be 41.